# Scraping data from basketball reference and it is not looping through full url

Tags: python, pandas, screen-scraping

The code only loops up to this point in the url 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{0}' and nothing after, so it is grabbing the incorrect data on an incorrect url

```
team_abbrev = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Desktop\NBA\team_abbreviations.csv')



for i in team_abbrev:
    url = ('https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{0}/2022/gamelog-advanced/#tgl_advanced').format(i)

    team_perf = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't iterating through the rows in your .csv or pd dataframe. First you need to load your csv into your dataframe, then you need to iterate through that dataframe:

```py
def baskiceball():

    filename = 'C:/Users/Me/Desktop/teams.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for x in range(0, len(row)):
            url = f'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{row[x]}/2022/gamelog-advanced/#tgl_advanced'
            r = requests.get(url)
            data = r.status_code
            print(f"{row[x]}" + " | " + f"{data}")
baskiceball()
```

My teams.csv document has the team abbreviations in a single column:

```
team_abbreviation
SAC
GSW
```

You plug `row[x]` into the query string

You make the request `r = requests.get(url)`

You read the request. In this instance I went with `r.status_code` since the url doesn't return json and I just wanted to show that it works. The result:

```
SAC | 200
GSW | 200
```